# Vim: what happened to <cr>?

Tags: vim

In Vim, <cr>  is/was customarily used to say something like "here we press ENTER key" when mapping shortcuts. It used to work that way even in Vim 7.3. In Vim 7.4, at least in my Linux-compiled version (without source changes) and in the vanilla-from-the-Windows-installer version (running in Windows this one, of course), the  doesn't work anymore. That breaks a hell of plugins and my own code.

I have been [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3CCR%3E+not+working+in+vim) this issue, but I can't find it. What am I missing?

Here is the result of "echo &compatible":

```
0
```

Here is an easy way to see the problem:

```
nmap r iHola<CR><ESC>
```

Then press "r", and a nice

```
Hola<CR><ESC>
```

is inserted in the file. In Vim 7.3, you get only "Hola" inserted in the file, and a new line.

Here is the output from ":version"

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 19 2013 17:58:08)
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +cryptv          +file_in_path    +linebreak       +mouse_sgr       +python          +tag_binary      +viminfo
+autocmd         +cscope          +find_in_path    +lispindent      -mouse_sysmouse  -python3         +tag_old_static  +vreplace
+balloon_eval    +cursorbind      +float           +listcmds        +mouse_urxvt     +quickfix        -tag_any_white   +wildignore
+browse          +cursorshape     +folding         +localmap        +mouse_xterm     +reltime         -tcl             +wildmenu
++builtin_terms  +dialog_con_gui  -footer          +lua             +multi_byte      +rightleft       +terminfo        +windows
+byte_offset     +diff            +fork()          +menu            +multi_lang      +ruby            +termresponse    +writebackup
+cindent         +digraphs        +gettext         +mksession       -mzscheme        +scrollbind      +textobjects     +X11
+clientserver    +dnd             -hangul_input    +modify_fname    +netbeans_intg   +signs           +title           -xfontset
+clipboard       -ebcdic          +iconv           +mouse           +path_extra      +smartindent     +toolbar         +xim
+cmdline_compl   +emacs_tags      +insert_expand   +mouseshape      -perl            -sniff           +user_commands   +xsmp_interact
+cmdline_hist    +eval            +jumplist        +mouse_dec       +persistent_undo +startuptime     +vertsplit       +xterm_clipboard
+cmdline_info    +ex_extra        +keymap          -mouse_gpm       +postscript      +statusline      +virtualedit     -xterm_save
+comments        +extra_search    +langmap         -mouse_jsbterm   +printer         -sun_workshop    +visual
+conceal         +farsi           +libcall         +mouse_netterm   +profile         +syntax          +visualextra
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

Question: Why <cr> does not work in Vim 7.4?

Comment: `<CR>` is still the same. You forgot to describe your problem: how and where do you use `<CR>`, what does not work when you use it, how does it fail?

Comment: @glts Hi there! Check my edits... my guess is that I'm missing something really obvious, but no idea what.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: `<CR>` works in 7.4. Could it be related to `:help cpoptions`? Please show us your vimrc and your plugins.

Comment: @romainl Yes, it was exactly cpoptions!  Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<CR>` works perfectly in Vim 7.4. It's something in your setup.

I'd hazard some plugin has mapped `<CR>` to something else.

Anyway, generally and exactly because of spurious unwanted remappings such as this one here, it is recommended to always use the non-remapping variant of the `:map` command. This should solve your problem.

```
:nnoremap r iHola<CR><ESC>
```

After reading @romainl's comment I dived into `'cpoptions'` and found the [`<` cpo-flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#cpo-%3C) that disables key notation. So, resetting `'cpo'` should at least eliminate this possibility.

```
:set cpo&vim
```

Comment: Really glad I found this... My problem was with cpoptions as well; it looks like the cygwin build of vim I'm using sets all the options by default. No idea why.