# Using <Esc> in vim insert mode results to <Esc> in text

Tags: vim, dictionary

I wanted to map the following sequence in vim to insert bracelets.

```
:map ( i() <Esc>hi
```

Whit this map I can insert bracelets from command mode and start typing inside the bracelets in insert mode.
But when i use this map i get the following result inserted in my text.

```
() <Esc>hi
```

As far as I understand the program doesn't use the  command it simply types it in insert mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: what happened to <cr>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476244/vim-what-happened-to-cr)

Comment: "bracelets" are more commonly known as parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the `<` flag in your `'cpoptions'`. Check with `:set cpo?`. To turn it off `:set cpo-=<`, but pay attention that you're not accidentally running in *compatible* mode; you don't want that!

> ```
> Disable the recognition of special key codes in <>
> form in mappings, abbreviations, and the "to" part of
> menu commands.
> ```

With regards to your mapping, there's no need to exit and re-enter insert mode. You can use `<Left>` (assuming you've fixed the literal insertion issue):

```
:map ( i() <Left><Left>
```

Comment: assuming you would want this while in insert mode, then: `:inoremap ( ()<Esc>i`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
:map ( i()<esc>i
```

With hi, you start before the first paranthesis since after  it places you on the last paranthesis.